# How would I take the top layer in a group, and make it's color overlay only show on children in the group?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, mask

Not sure if anyone can help, but I'm looking to see if it's possible to do.

Can I have a group of layers in Photoshop, fill the entire canvas with a color and have it only show on the children of that group below the fill layer?

Comment: Yes! You just need to use a mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; use a [Clipping Mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/clipping-masks.html).

Take your group...

[image]

Create your fill above the group...

[image]

With the fill layer selected, either go to *Image → Create Clipping Mask*, or simply <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> directly between the group and the fill layer in the Layers panel.

[image]